# PHP: DateTime '-1 day'

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the date of yesterday of the current date in a specifc time zone.
I tried like this, but it is not working:

```
$date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake')); 
$yesterday = $date->modify( '-1 day' );
$yesterday = $yesterday->format('Y-m-d');
```

I am still getting today's date.

Comment: Have you tried not setting $date again?  Just create the object once, and then set new variables to that value?  Eg, `$date = new DateTime(); $date->modify(); echo $date->format();`.  Note; I left out information for brevity.  In other words; I don't know if DateTime is chainable.

Comment: The issue seems to lie in your first line of code, so try to remove `NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake')` to read as `$date = new DateTime();` or choose a similar timezone.

Comment: You can also try adding `date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Wake');` or use `echo 'Yesterday was: ' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday'));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem, according to the [documentation for the `modify()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), seems to entirely depend on which version of php you're using.  In this case, method chaining(which is what you're attempting to do is called), is only available on php version 5.3.0 and up, according to the [changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php#refsect1-datetime.modify-changelog) on the previously linked docs.

That in mind, it explains why your code didn't work, and @Deryck's did.  If you ever do upgrade your php version, or get your host to upgrade it, you could likely reduce those three lines to two:

```
$date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake')); 
$date = $date->modify( '-1 day' )->format('Y-m-d');
```

Not much of an improvement, I realize, but there's your reason for why it failed to work.

Below are two of the methods I see of getting around this; one is creation of a class.. which seems like overkill to me unless this is apart of something grander... the other is a creation of a function.  Both shove the extra lines into something that takes up less space, in a sense.

```
class DT {
    private $now; //can be null
    private $timezone; //DateTimeZone object
    public function __construct($tz_str, $now = NULL) {
        $this->now = $now;
        $this->timezone = new DateTimeZone($tz_str);;
    }

    public function mod($mod,$format) {
      $dt = new DateTime($this->now, $this->timezone);
      $dt->modify($mod);
      return $dt->format($format);
    }
}

function mod_formatted_zone($tz_str, $mod, $format, $now = NULL) {
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($tz_str);
    $dt = new DateTime($now,$timezone);
    $dt->modify($mod);
    return $dt->format($format);
}
```

The use of either is simple; in the case of the class, it'd be something like..

```
$dt = new DT('Pacific/Wake');
echo $dt->mod('-1 day', 'Y-m-d');
```

While in the case of the function, it'd simply be..

```
echo mod_formatted_zone('Pacific/Wake', '-1 day', 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Further, given the above two lines, you can just create more variables as needed: `$date1 = $date->modify(blahblah)->format(blah);`, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Gotta love chaining.  `return this` ftw

Comment: Thanks. But this does not work on my installation. So I have to either create a new DateTime for every date I want (yesterday, tomorrow, date of monday,...) or I set it with `date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Wake');` and go for the old `date()` function. What's your recommendation?

Comment: @yoshi Well, I see two ways of doing it; either create a class to hold the variables and methods, or a simple function to return that sort of well, stuffs all of that in just one line.  I can post both, if you want.  I have them written up.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work once you don't re-assign the `$date` variable unnecessarily.  See below:

```
<?php 
  $date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake'));
  $date->modify("-1 day");
  $date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
  // echo $date; // just in case you wanna echo - ya dig
?>
```

### [View demo](http://codepad.org/7uIEWbXW)

**FYI:**

> Wake Island Time Zone (UTC+12:00)

Which means 1 day before is actually *today* (for me at least, on the western hemisphere).

Comment: I should have answered :/

Comment: oh wow haha yeah go post one i'll delete mine i didnt even notice

Comment: @Daedalus comment here when you post it so I know to come back here after leaving

Comment: @Deryck off-topic: don't be so humble. You did take the time to post an answer. You deserve the credit ;-)

Comment: lol I guess I just feel bad.  StackOverflow is like the Kentucky Derby of code sprints on crack

Comment: @Deryck Better idea; keep your answer, I'll add mine, we'll both vote each other up, heh.

Comment: @Daedalus haha you sly dog you

Comment: Ok, but I need `$date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake'));` for other variables too. For example I want to get the date of monday of this week. So should I create it for each variable?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the date of yesterday of the current date in a specifc time zone.

You can specify relative dates in the DateTime constructor. This will work for you:-

```
$yesterday = new DateTime('- 1 day', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake'));
var_dump($yesterday);
```

[Proof!](http://3v4l.org/8554e).